# Error trying to connect Google Earth Engine API in Node.js Server

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to develop a nodejs app that uses Google earth engine for some geospatial data analisys. I'm using **"@google/earthengine": "^0.1.185", node v16.4.2 and npm v 7.18.1. I also created the service account with gcloud and followed the step by step Google Earth Engine [npm installation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/npm_install)**. The problem is, everytime I call some earth engine feature it just give the error:

```
throw ee.initializationFailure_(e), e;
          ^

Error: Failed to contact Earth Engine servers. Please check your connection, firewall, or browser extension settings
```

before I just got 404 error when trying to connect to earth engine. I tried to deactivate my firewall as well as change the internet I was using, still the same.
See the code down and the error:

```
const ee = require('@google/earthengine');
const path = require("path");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const privateKey = require('./privatekey.json');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
//app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "html");


app.get('/', (_,res)=>{
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root : __dirname + '/views'});
});
// Define endpoint at /mapid.
app.get('/mapid', (_, response) => {
  // Instantiate an image with the Image constructor.
  var image = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4');

  // Zoom to a location.
  Map.setCenter(-112.8598, 36.2841, 9); // Center on the Grand Canyon.

  // Display the image on the map.
  Map.addLayer(image);
   
});

console.log('Authenticating Earth Engine API using private key...');

ee.data.authenticateViaPrivateKey(
    privateKey,
    () => {
      console.log('Authentication successful.');
      ee.initialize(() => {
        console.log('Earth Engine client library initialized.');
        app.listen(port);
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
      },
      (err) => {
       
        console.log(err);
       
      });
      
    },
    (err) => {
      
       console.log(err);
      
    });
 

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

**the error**

```
C:\blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:17724
          throw ee.initializationFailure_(e), e;
          ^

Error: Failed to contact Earth Engine servers. Please check your connection, firewall, or browser extension settings.
    at Object.ee.data.handleResponse_ (C:\blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:15467:9)
    at Object.ee.data.send_ (C:\blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:15390:18)
    at Object.ee.data.getAlgorithms (C:\blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:14670:24)
    at Function.ee.ApiFunction.initialize (C:\blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:15923:78)
    at Object.ee.initialize (C:\blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:17722:26)
    at blablablabla\app.js:36:10
    at Object.ee.data.handleAuthResult_ (C:\blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:15497:16)
    at blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:14490:19
    at blablablabla\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:14424:41
    at blablablabla\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\auth\jwtclient.js:119:5
```

please I really need your help.

Comment: Did you [signup](https://signup.earthengine.google.com/#!/)?

Comment: Yes i did, and it was aproved. I

Comment: Have you tested the installation with this code: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/npm_install#testing-the-installation

Comment: yes @tttony, i have tried but also getting error `throw ee.initializationFailure_(e), e;
          ^

Error: Server returned HTTP code: 404`

Comment: I think the error in the the initialize. Try to use [this](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/a0133e96a3040af00612b1159f39fc30#file-npm-google-earth-inicialization-md)  #1 Which route throws the error? / or /mapid #2 After read [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/npm_install) and its examples, I can see that the main usage is for standalone applications not for server side.  #3 What does `Map.addLayer` ? returns a jpg? #4 Could you try first in standalone mode? If works,  I can help you to use it in a server side app  (express)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your computer cannot even contact the google engine service server. Maybe you should try to test your code in another computer, which doesn't have any firewall, proxy or anything else that might interfere your networking.

Also, since you're in `İstanbul, Istambul, Turquia`, which [interferes with Google services](https://www.cruisersforum.com/forums/f17/turkey-blocks-google-earth-and-google-maps-42538.html) occasionally, make sure the google earth engine service isn't blocked when you're testing. If you're sure it's the case, then you might need a proxy or vpn. Or if you're using proxy/vpn, make sure the proxy/vpn allows google engine services.